# Blackberry: How to get raw content of Node when parsing XML

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to pull an html string out of some XML returned through a SOAP Web Service call. My Node object is of the following class:

`org.w3c.dom.Node`

Here is a code sample of the loop I use to go through nodes:

```
for(int t = 0; t < elements; t++)
{

         Element myElement = (Element)elements.item(t);

         NodeList childNodes = myElement.getChildNodes();
         int numChildren = childNodes.getLength();

         for(int counter = 0; counter < numChildren; counter++)
         {
             Node currentNode = childNodes.item(counter);
             NodeList currentNodeChildNodes = currentNode.getChildNodes();

             int numCurrentNodeChildren = currentNodeChildNodes.getLength();
             Node firstChild = currentNodeChildNodes.item( 0 );
         }
}
```

Now, some of these Nodes contain raw html. Which of course makes it look like they have children. I would like to take these html Nodes and get all of its' contents straight into a `String`. I tried `currentNode.getTextContent()` and it just produces a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Is there a method I can use to just take the node and get it's raw content as a String, regardless of whether or not it contains child nodes?

**EDIT: Here's an example of the XML with html content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetInfoResponse xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/">
      <GetInfoResult>
        <infoList>
          <Info>
            <iso>US</iso>
            <country_name>United States</country_name>
            <title>This is the title</title>
            <html_string><strong>NEWS</strong><h1>This is a section header</h1><p>Here is some information</p></html_string>
            <last_update_date>2013-01-01 00:00:00</last_update_date>
          </Info>
        </infoList>
        <faultResponse>
          <faultOccurred>boolean</faultOccurred>
          <faultDescription>string</faultDescription>
        </faultResponse>
      </GetInfoResult>
    </GetInfoResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: where does the NPE come from?

Comment: from the getTextContent() method. Not sure why exactly, but I stopped worrying about that because, as I later realized, currentNode.getTextContent() is not at all what I'm looking for.

Comment: why is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Because it doesn't exactly treat the html string as text content. It's seen as containing more children, getTextContent() is supposedly a way to get all the actual text content and concatenate it into one string. I want the html as is, with it's tags.

Comment: your html content is embedded within the xml as xml content?  can you post an example xml document?

Comment: Please see my example, it's been simplified a whole lot but it gets the point across. I want to take that html as it is and use it in a web view or something similar

Comment: Can you change the service at all? This is a rather unusual way of including HTML in XML. RSS for instance just escapes the tags, which is arguably less error-prone since HTML doesn't necessarily have to be valid XML.

Comment: Well I could change the service but this all works fine on the other platforms I program for (iOS, Android). I would like to keep it as is if possible.

Comment: My point is that if you usually want to treat the HTML content as an atomic string, it'd be easier (on all platforms) when you send it in the web service as a string, not as XML content. (Using escaping or CDATA, if you don't want to include CDATA sections in the HTML itself.)

Comment: Otherwise, you could just reserialise the document into a `String` on the blackberry, but I don't have a JDK on hand and the code is too hairy to write from memory. (The basic idea is you create a new `Document`, import the child nodes of `html_string` into it, write the document out into a `StringWriter`, and get its contents.)

Comment: i agree w/ @millimoose, this is a bad idea.  what happens if your html is not valid xml?  then you'll end up with parsing errors on _every_ platform.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad idea to mix html and xml content.  while html *can* be formatted like xml (xhtml), it quite often is not.  by mixing the two, you run the risk of causing xml parsing failures in the future when your html does not happen to be valid xml.  instead, you should should encode your html content as a valid xml element value.  if you do this, then you can get the data in java using a `Node.getTextContent()` call on the `html_string` element.